# Echo value from PHP array when brackets in key-value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

Quick question, how do you echo a variable when the array has key's that contain names with brackets etc. See array below:

```
 [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 4
                [contact_id] => 
                [status] => Complete
                [is_test_data] => 0
                [datesubmitted] => 2014-04-16 22:18:39
                [sResponseComment] => 
                [responseID] => 4
                [[question(1), option(0)]] => 
                [[question(2)]] => John
                [[question(3)]] => Wtf@wtf.com
                [[question(5)]] => 0975735289
                [[question(6)]] => 3010
                [[question(9), option(0)]] => 
                [[question(10)]] => Testing
                [[question(11)]] => Later
                [[question(12)]] => This year


            )
```

Lets say i want to echo the answer to question 2, which is "John". How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have an array conataining an array of objects:

```
echo $array['data'][0]->{'[question(2)]'};
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going in a complete different direction, I will accept answer now. Thanks again!